# Error: Unable to upload artifact HelloWorldFunction referenced by CodeUri parameter of HelloWorldFunction resource. AWS Lambda, SAM CLI, GitLab CI/CD

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, gitlab

The AWS user has all policies included. Removed Sam Package and auto packaging with Sam Deploy. Still having an issue with the CodeUri parameter of HelloWorldFunction resource and Access Denied while trying to deploy "Hello-World" lambda function to S3 bucket. The package build and deploy works fine from my Mac Machine. The issue only occurs with GitLab CI/CD pipeline.

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/apn/using-gitlab-ci-cd-pipeline-to-deploy-aws-sam-applications/

```
$ sam build


SAM CLI now collects telemetry to better understand customer needs.

You can OPT OUT and disable telemetry collection by setting the
environment variable SAM_CLI_TELEMETRY=0 in your shell.
Thanks for your help!

Learn More: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/serverless-sam-telemetry.html

Building function 'HelloWorldFunction'
Running PythonPipBuilder:ResolveDependencies
Running PythonPipBuilder:CopySource

Build Succeeded

Built Artifacts  : .aws-sam/build
Built Template   : .aws-sam/build/template.yaml

Commands you can use next
=========================
[*] Invoke Function: sam local invoke
[*] Deploy: sam deploy --guided

$ sam package --output-template-file packaged.yaml --s3-bucket hello-tilak

Error: Unable to upload artifact HelloWorldFunction referenced by 
CodeUri parameter of HelloWorldFunction resource.
An error occurred (AccessDenied) when calling the PutObject operation: 
Access Denied
ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1
```

Comment: Which exactly policies you are referring in "The AWS user has all policies included." Also, does the "AWS user" you are referring is the same one as you setup in GitLab?

Comment: I created a user in IAM and gave full access to Lambda, S3, CloudWatch, APIGateWay, IAM, and CloudFormation. I added AWS user's access key and secret key in the Gitlab. I am able to package and deploy from my Mac, but the issue occurs only when setting up the Gitlab pipeline.

Comment: Yeah, we ran into exactly this "works from my Mac, but not from GL CI". For now, we've more-or-less given up on automating SAM deploys until it matures more. Just check out [their repo for the CLI](https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sam-cli/releases): it's getting updates about every week.

Comment: It probably works on the local box because the CLI resolves the default profile that is set in the credentials file or in the environment variables. I suggest specifying the [profile](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html#:~:text=in%20your%20template.-,%2D%2Dprofile%20TEXT,-The%20specific%20profile) switch explicitly to use the profile that sets the required access & secret keys. 
For a CI/CD pipeline, it probably makes sense to use environment variables instead of profiles.

Answer (score 1):

The [SAM CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/install-sam-cli.html) uses the [AWS SDK](https://www.npmjs.com/package/aws-sdk) underneath to interact with AWS services. The AWS SDK, by default, looks for credentials in the `default` profile unless specified otherwise. If your AWS setup on GitLab CI/CD or any other environment does not use the `default` profile (or if the `default` profile does not have the necessary permissions), then you would indeed encounter such errors.

Steps like [`sam package`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-package.html) or [`sam deploy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/serverless-application-model/latest/developerguide/sam-cli-command-reference-sam-deploy.html) do require AWS credentials as they interact with AWS services like Amazon S3 or CloudFormation.

For those using CI/CD pipelines or automated systems, it is common to use environment variables (`AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID`, `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY`, and optionally `AWS_SESSION_TOKEN` for temporary credentials) instead of profiles. Check also if your CI/CD job has set the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable: the AWS SDK will use that profile for operations.

You can also provide the `--profile <profile_name>` flag, which explicitly instructs SAM CLI (and AWS SDK) to use the named profile from the AWS configuration. If this named profile has the necessary permissions, then the operation should succeed.

To determine which AWS profile you are using (or if you are even using one), check the config**: AWS CLI configuration is typically stored in [`~/.aws/config` and the credentials are in `~/.aws/credentials`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-configure.html). You can inspect these files to see which profiles are defined and what the default configuration looks like. Note that if you are on a CI/CD system or a non-interactive environment, the location and presence of these files might differ.

---

> now that I have realized that the profile user I used to develop the cloud formation needs all permissions to the resources in use, is there a way to grant those permissions to the user by coding instead of authorizing them on the console website?

You can programmatically manage AWS IAM permissions using the [AWS Command Line Interface (AWS CLI)](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/index.html), [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/developer/tools/), or [AWS CloudFormation](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/).

### AWS CLI

You can use the AWS CLI to manage IAM roles, policies, and permissions, with [`create-policy`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/create-policy.html) and [`attach-user-policy`](https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/iam/attach-user-policy.html).

```bash
# Create a new IAM policy from a JSON file
aws iam create-policy --policy-name MyPolicy --policy-document file://mypolicy.json

# Attach the policy to a user
aws iam attach-user-policy --policy-arn arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT_ID:policy/MyPolicy --user-name MyUserName
```

The file `mypolicy.json` should contain your policy in JSON format.

### AWS SDK

AWS SDKs (like [Boto3 for Python](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-python/)) allow for robust programmatic management of AWS resources, including [IAM permissions](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/security.html#identity-and-access-management-intro): see [`IAM.Client`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/iam.html)

```py
import boto3

# Create an IAM client
iam = boto3.client('iam')

# Create a new IAM policy
with open('mypolicy.json', 'r') as file:
    policy = file.read()

response = iam.create_policy(PolicyName='MyPolicy', PolicyDocument=policy)
policy_arn = response['Policy']['Arn']

# Attach the policy to a user
iam.attach_user_policy(UserName='MyUserName', PolicyArn=policy_arn)
```

### AWS CloudFormation**:

You can also manage IAM permissions as part of your infrastructure using [AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudformation/index.html). See [How can I attach an IAM managed policy to an IAM role in AWS CloudFormation?](https://repost.aws/knowledge-center/cloudformation-attach-managed-policy) as an example, using [`AWS::IAM::ManagedPolicy`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-iam-managedpolicy.html).

Comment: Thanks! It actually aligns with what I later figured out myself! Just one more question: now that I have realized that the profile user I used to develop the cloud formation needs all permissions to the resources in use, is there a way to grant those permissions to the user by coding instead of authorizing them on the console website?